# define instance method objective c that returns boolean

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to 
Define a instance method in Objective-C called "print" that returns a boolean value and takes in a string parameter called "toPrint".

I'm using (BOOL)print:("str")"toPrint" but unsure if correct syntax

Comment: If one of the answers helps, [it's customary to accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), to mark the question as answered.  It benefits you, us, and other users who visit the question.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
- (BOOL)print:(NSString *)toPrint
{
    ...
    return YES;
}
```

... but you would do better with longer, more descriptive method names and parameters.

[Objective C method conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) suggest names where the method can expressively be spoken, such as `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock`

The other thing you have to avoid is clashes with other methods or properties in the namespace.  Longer, less common names avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)print:(NSString *)toPrint {
...
}
```

You need to read more about Objective C :)